# Powershell foreach help. Can someone help so that it only loops once?

Tags: powershell, loops, for-loop, foreach, robocopy

For an example I want it to say

robocopy "C:\SCRIPT TEST" "C:\NEW TEST" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile

robocopy "C:\SCRIPT TEST 2" "C:\NEW TESTT" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile

and not loop more than once. Is there a way to run the foreach loop at the same time? I hope its clear thank you!

```
$Logfile = "C:\NEW TEST 2\robocopylog.txt"

$sources = @("SCRIPT TEST", "SCRIPT TEST 2")
$destinations = @("NEW TEST", "NEWTESTT")

foreach ($source in $sources){
    foreach ($destination in $destinations){

        robocopy "C:\$source" "C:\$destination" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile

}
}
```

Comment: Need it for many different sources and destinations so a loop is necessary. so far none of the answers work...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop

```
$Logfile = "C:\NEW TEST 2\robocopylog.txt"

$sources = @("SCRIPT TEST", "SCRIPT TEST 2")
$destinations = @("NEW TEST", "NEWTESTT")

for($i = 0; $i -lt $sources.Count; $i++){
    Write-Host robocopy "C:\$($sources[$i])" "C:\$($destinations[0])" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile
}
```

But I'd really recommend you rethink your approach. I think a hash table or PSCustomObject would be more appropriate storage structures.

```
$paths = @{
    Source      = "SCRIPT TEST"
    Destination = "NEW TEST"
},
@{
    Source      = "SCRIPT TEST 2"
    Destination = "NEWTESTT"
}

$paths.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host robocopy "C:\$($_.source)" "C:\$($_.destination)" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile
}
```

or

```
$paths = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Source      = "SCRIPT TEST"
    Destination = "NEW TEST"
},
[PSCustomObject]@{
    Source      = "SCRIPT TEST 2"
    Destination = "NEWTESTT"
}

foreach($path in $paths){
    Write-Host robocopy "C:\$($path.source)" "C:\$($path.destination)" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile
}
```

Comment: In Powershell 5 (and maybe later version too, not sure since when) you wouldn't even have to convert to `PSCustomObject` to access the keys like properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'd address the arrays by index, rather than using the `foreach` iterator. Then you copy `$source[$i]` to `$destination[$i]`, something along the lines of:

```
if ($sources.length -ne $destinations.length) {
    throw "Number of sources does not match number of destinations" 
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $sources.Length; $i++) {
    "$($sources[$i]) -> $($destinations[$i])" 
}
```

The first check exists for hopefully obvious reasons. Swapping in the robocopy is should be fairly trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass arrays with 2 elements and have nested loops, this is what it does - it will loop for each element.

What you want is an array with 2 dimensions and one loop:

```
$sources = @( ("SCRIPT TEST", "NEW TEST"), ("SCRIPT TEST 2", "NEWTESTT") )

foreach ($source in $sources)
{
    robocopy "C:\$($source[0])" "C:\$($source[1])" /Z /W:5 /MIR /LOG+:$Logfile
}
```